# Como substituir código de imagem nos posts?

Tags: wordpress

Ao inserir uma imagem pelo botão "Add Media", o WP gera um código HTML, como:

```
<a href="http://host/linkdaIMG"><img src="http://img.cdn.net/papel.jpg" alt="image_name" width="800" height="600" class="image_class" /></a>
```

Alguém sabe se existe algum plugin ou código que reescreva esse código gerado pelo WP? Por exemplo: Eu quero que o código seja sobrescrito e exiba

```
<a href="http://host/linkdaIMG"><img src="http://img2.cdn.net/800x600/papel.jpg" alt="image_name" class="image_class" /></a>
```

Porém eu não quero que o output do botão "Add Media" mude, mas que o código seja alterado na leitura do post, porque ai os posts antigos seriam ajustados também.

Comment: Remover os atributos da tag `img` é tranquilo. Agora, você quer alterar o caminho da sua imagem com base nesses parâmetros? É isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso @CaioFelipePereira. Eu quero poder utilizar os parâmetros da imagem pra poder montar a URL dela como eu quiser... que fica mais fácil quando eu utilizar um manipulador de imagens via url.

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, acredito que a a melhor solução seria usar um [Parser de HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), que permite que você encontre as *tags* do HTML assim como com jQuery. Porém, não sei como o seu código do WP está estruturado, e nem se você pode incluir a biblioteca (motivos empresariais ou whatever), portanto, vou propor uma solução usando expressões regulares.

**Full Disclaimer**: Expressões regulares são custosas e podem causar lentidão, e a que eu escrevi provavelmente pode ser escrita de uma maneira mais inteligente. Eu estou assumindo também que o WordPress *sempre* vai devolver os links usando *double quotation marks* (i.e., `"` e não `'`). Caso amanhã eles resolvam mudar, essa solução vai cair. Por fim, a extração dos atributos não é nada elegante, o que pode causar reações adversas nos programadores mais experientes.

O segredo da coisa, no que se diz respeito ao mundo do WP, é usar os filtros corretos. Mais especificamente, dois. Filtros servem para invocar métodos em determinados momentos, e você pode ler mais sobre filtros [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). Neste caso

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'build_custom_url', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'build_custom_url', 10 );
```

são os filtros necessários. Basta agora criar o método `build_custom_url()` para interceptar o HTML gerado pelo WP e modificá-lo de acordo com as suas necessidades.

Usando [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), é possível comparar o conteúdo de uma *string* ($html) com os parâmetros da RegEx e guardá-las em um array(`$result)`. Fazendo

```
preg_match_all('/(width|height|src)=("[^"]*")/i', $html, $result);

print_r($result);
```

você obtém (por exemplo):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => width="247"
            [1] => height="359"
            [2] => src="http://localhost:8880/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/pg.png"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => width
            [1] => height
            [2] => src
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "247"
            [1] => "359"
            [2] => "http://localhost:8880/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/pg.png"
        )
)
```

Eu fiz esse teste recebendo o HTML que o próprio WP me forneceu, através de um desses filtros. Veja que, agora, você pode fazer

```
$width = $result[2][0];
$height = $result[2][1];
$src = substr($result, strrpos($result, '/') + 1); //necessário para extraír o nome do arquivo.
```

Veja que agora é simples você construir (e retornar) o seu HTML como queira, com base nesses parâmetros. Com isso, o código final fica

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'build_custom_url', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'build_custom_url', 10 );

function build_custom_url( $html ) {

    preg_match_all('/(width|height|src)=("[^"]*")/i', $html, $result);

    $width = $result[2][0];
    $height = $result[2][1];
    $src = substr($result, strrpos($result, '/') + 1); //necessário para extraír o nome do arquivo.

    // Reconstruindo a URL. Aqui você adequa a sua necessidade real
    $html = '<img src=http://meusite/'.$width.'x'.$height.'/'.$src;
    return $html;
}
```

Adeque este código à sua necessidade, e adicione-o ao seu arquivo `functions.php`, e tudo deve funcionar.